# mod_rewrite rule (dynamic to static URI) not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cjk

I am trying to rewrite the following dynamic URI:

> http://domain.com/dictionary/?h=%E8%AF%91

To this:

> http://domain.com/dictionary/%E8%AF%91

Note that %E8%AF%91 is the Chinese character 译.

I am using the following mod_rewrite in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dictionary/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?h=$1
```

I have also tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dictionary/([^/\.]+)/?$ dictionary/index.php?h=$1
```

I am not sure why it is working. Some theories that I have:

- Chinese characters need a particular workaround for mod_rewrite
- WordPress's rewrite rules are messing with mine

I have checked and mod_rewrite is **definitely** activated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest capturing against %{THE_REQUEST} with a rewritecond which will give you the original, client-encoded form of the URL  in e.g. %1.

You should then find it much easier to re-substitute that capture into the new URL.